# python mutable string class not working correctly

Tags: python, string

I created a mutable String class in Python, based on the builtin `str` class.

I can change the first character, but when I call `capitalize()`, it uses the old value instead

```
class String(str):

    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = list(string)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "".join(self.string)

    def __str__(self):
        return "".join(self.string)

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.string[index] = value

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if type(index) == slice:
            return "".join(self.string[index])
        return self.string[index]

    def __delitem__(self, index):
        del self.string[index]

    def __add__(self, other_string):
        return String("".join(self.string) + other_string)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.string)

text = String("cello world")
text[0] = "h"
print(text)
print(text.capitalize())
```

> **Expected Output :**
>
> ```
> hello world
>
> Hello world
> ```
>
> **Actual Output :**
>
> ```
> hello world
>
> Cello world
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is inferior to the already suggested answers. There is more overhead because you don't get to just track things as a list, and `isinstance(s, str)` won't work, for example.

Another way to accomplish this is to subclass [`collections.UserString`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.UserString). It's a wrapper around the built-in string type that stores it as a member named `data`. So you could do something like

```
from collections import UserString

class String(UserString):
    def __init__(self, string):
        super().__init__(string)
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        data_list = list(self.data)
        data_list[index] = value
        self.data = "".join(data_list)
    # etc.
```

And then you will get `capitalize` and the other string methods for free.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation inherits from `str`, so it brings along all the methods that `str` implements. However, the implementation of the `str.capitalize()` method is not designed to take that into account. Methods like `str.capitalize()` return a *new* `str` object with the required change applied.

Moreover, the Python built-in types do not store their state in a `__dict__` mapping of attributes, but use [internal `struct` data structures](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cee95fe1825dfeb52d7074c8209b5884a079f06c/Include/unicodeobject.h#L193-L357)) only accessible on the C level; your `self.string` attribute is not where the [(C equivalent of) `str.__new__()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cee95fe1825dfeb52d7074c8209b5884a079f06c/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L1261-L1373) stores the string data. The `str.capitalize()` method bases its return value on the value stored in the internal data structure when the instance was created, which can't be altered from Python code.

You'll have to shadow all the `str` methods that return a new value, including `str.capitalize()` to behave differently. If you want those methods from returning a new instance to changing the value in-place, you have to do so yourself:

```
class String(str):
    # ...

    def capitalize(self):
        """Capitalize the string, in place""" 
        self.string[:] ''.join(self.string).capitalize()
        return self  # or return None, like other mutable types would do
```

That can be a lot of work, writing methods like these for every possible `str` method that returns an updated value. Instead, you could use a `__getattribute__` hook to redirect methods:

```
_MUTATORS = {'capitalize', 'lower', 'upper', 'replace'}  # add as needed

class String(str):
    # ...

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in _MUTATORS:
            def mutator(*args, **kwargs):
                orig = getattr(''.join(self.string), name)
                self.string[:] = orig(*args, **kwargs)
                return self  # or return None for Python type consistency
            mutator.__name__ = name
            return mutator
        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

Demo with the `__getattribute__` method above added to your class:

```
>>> text = String("cello world")
>>> text[0] = "h"
>>> print(text)
hello world
>>> print(text.capitalize())
Hello world
>>> print(text)
Hello world
```

One side note: the `__repr__` method should use `repr()` to return a proper representation, not just the value:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return repr(''.join(self.string))
```

Also, take into account that most Python APIs that are coded in C and take a `str` value as input, are likely to use the [C API for Unicode strings](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#unicode-objects) and so not only completely ignore your custom implementations but like the original `str.capitalize()` method will also ignore the `self.string` attribute. Instead, they too will interact with the internal `str` data.

Comment: Given all this, is there any benefit gained by this class inheriting from `str`?

Comment: @khelwood: it'll test as a string anywhere `isinstance(object, str)` is used. Given that there is no `collections.abc` type you can use instead, that's a decent reason to continue doing this.

Comment: Won't that be rather misleading?

Comment: @khelwood: that depends on what the OP hopes to use this class for.

Comment: @khelwood: and in programming, there is no such thing as 'misleading', that's what inheritance is all about! To extend and alter behaviour but still be compatible with the interface of the parent class.

Comment: "compatible" in the sense of having a bunch of methods that look like the methods you expect, but actually do something quite different...

Comment: Is there a way to get all methods of `str` ? This way I can loop through them and redefine them using a lambda or something else

Comment: @khelwood: yes, so? That's how a lot of objects work. `list`, `tuple`, `bytes` and `str` are all sequences, so have a lot of methods in common. Yet their implementations are very different for all that the method names and signatures are the same.

Comment: @MichaelFish: Use `vars(str)` to get a dictionary of all attributes that the type defines. Methods are just attributes that happen to be callable (and usually, implement the descriptor protocol). Take into account there is at least one *static method* on the type, `str.maketrans()`.

Comment: @MichaelFish: there are also methods that return something other than a `str`, such as tests that return a boolean (`__contains__()`, `isupper()`, `isdigit()`, `startswith()`, etc.), or return a list or tuple (`split()`, `partition()`, `rsplit()`, `rpartition()`, etc.). There is no one-size-fits-all approach here, I fear.

Comment: I guess your "that depends on what the OP hopes to use this class for" is covering this ground, but my objection to it is that if I have a function that accepts a string as an argument (and I confirm it is a `str` with `isinstance`), then I expect to be able to call `y = x.capitalize()` etc. and get the results prescribed by the usual `str` methods. To have something disguised as a `str` that has completely different behaviour seems like a great a way to introduce weird behaviours and confusing bugs into your program.

Comment: And if the OP's intended use does _not_ include passing their mutable strings into functions expecting normal strings, then why should it be desirable to have `isinstance(object, str)` return true?

Comment: @khelwood: Concatenation with other `str` values where `String()` is the right-hand value. For `a + b`, where `b` is a subclass of `type(a)`, `b.__radd__()` is [called before `a.__add__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__). This is specifically so you can override such operator overloads in a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You inherited `str`'s definition of `capitalize`, which ignores your class's behaviors and just uses the underlying data of the "real" `str`.

Inheriting from a built-in type like this effectively requires you to reimplement *every* method, or do some metaprogramming with `__getattribute__`; otherwise, the underlying type's behaviors will be inherited unmodified.